# Clicking on google results for my slideshow shows me only the first slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

I'm currently working on a project which involves several slideshows.

The slideshows get rendered on the page and after the html has been added JS is used to

> display:none

the divs that aren't active.

This all works fine. But when I google content that is in one of the slides I can find the slide data in google, but when I click the link I get linked to the first slide, not the relevant one.

I'm aware that google can see all the slides on one page (even if they are hidden, and will thus just link to that page. The question is, how to I get it to link to the correct slide ID ?

Comment: If you're using IDs for each slider on the same page make sure you're using anchors in the correct fashion, also, use of microdata might help `itemscope` etc.

Comment: Id's are being used but how is that related to the fact that google will just assume all those hidden divs are one "page" while it should probably be listing them as several pages.

Answer (score 0):

If your subsequent slides don't have dedicated individual pages with unique titles and descriptions, Google might rightly assume that bringing users to the first slide is the best option.

Also, if you use any sort of rel="prev" & rel="next" or canonical tag markup relating to these pages, this will drive Google to deliver the first in the series.